# How to use pseudo-op for an instruction?

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, x86-16

In an assembly language, how can I use pseudo-ops for an instruction? From what I know, an assembly file is converted to machine code using an assembler. Is there a way to directly send the op-code from the assembly file itself using pseudo-ops?

For example if there's some instruction, say ADD which has an op-code of 0101. Is there a way to use our that knowledge of ADD's op code being 0101 to just ADD two registers using 0101 from some memory location and not using the ADD instruction explicitly? I was looking for a hack and was wondering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an indirect opcode (retrieve the instruction byte from a data location specified in the instruction) is not supported in any machine language I know. But you have the following possibilities:

- Self-modifying code (You get write access to your own code segment and patch the code bytes on the fly)
- Create a (short) fragment of code in a data region, mark that region executable and jump into it (likely you will create a subroutine there, ending in 0xC3 if it is x86 assembly), and jump to it using the CALL instruction (or whatever it is called on your machine).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what assembler you're using, but GAS for example has the `.byte` pseudo-op to simply emit a byte. Note that 0101 is in binary notation which is probably not suitable for the assembler. You should specify opcodes in hexadecimal.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed in hex, but I was just giving an example. I wanted to know if I can store the op code in some memory location and fetch it to use that operation.

Comment: You can put a .byte right in-line with your assembly code if you wish.

Comment: In addition to what Jonathon pointed out regarding `gas`, with `nasm`, `yasm` compilers, it is simply `byte`, and with other compilers you may see `byteptr`.

Comment: The assembler I'm using only allows constants for pseudo ops and nothing else. I was looking for something like storing the op code in the stack and maybe executing as machine code.

Comment: You'll have to mark your stack as executable, probably tweaking the PE or ELF headers accordingly, or figuring out at runtime where your stack is mapped and making the appropriate API calls to change the protections.

Comment: Your question now seems to have almost nothing to do with the title. Is there something specific you're trying to accomplish? Do you have a higher-level goal? Perhaps we can suggest appropriate topics for you to research instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, and is in fact how buffer overflow or stack overrun exploits work to attack system security.  If binary values are stored into executable memory, they will be loaded and executed as machine language instructions, and 0101 will ADD (in your example).

Comment: So for example, if I store the value 0101 (in this example) to the stack, will it execute it as byte code and ADD the registers?

Comment: it's more complicated than that; the stack normally holds data values, so you have to trick the cpu into running code from it.  The key is that the stack also holds code addresses, and it's possible to get the cpu to confuse the two.  Wikipedia has a detailed writeup on it -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow